# VisualStudio2017(C#)でプロジェクトに空のFormを追加する方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio

最近プログラム環境を変えて、Windows7からWindows10に変更しました。
そのさいVSも2015から2017に変更したのですが、手順が変わったのか、
項目がなくなったのかよくわからなく、教えていただきたく願います。

【聞きたい内容：手順】
「VisualStudio2017のC#環境」で、ソリューションエクスプローラーから
右クリック[追加]を選び、空のWindowsフォームを追加する方法

上記手順で空のWindowsフォームが見当たりません。
2015までは上記手順で追加できていました。
実はこちらの環境が悪いだけで皆様にはあるのか、
ないのであれば皆様はどのように空のフォームを対応しているのか教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

VisualStudio Community2017 Version15.1(263404.0)
.NetFramework Version 4.6.01586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio をインストールする際に、Windows デスクトップアプリケーションの開発支援を追加し忘れた、とかは無いですか？

Comment: 「さすがに.net関連いれてないとかそんなわけないやろー」と調べてみたら.Netデスクトップ開発のインストールやってなかったです・・・。完全に頭から離れてました。本当にありがとうございます。